# how to make dynamic header table in php

Tags: php, mysql

i use PHP and MySQLi and i make an app. and i confused about the output i want show. how can i make a header dynamic. this is my data.

```
id || username    || bookid || durasi
1  || X3301000101 || 100B01 || 100
2  || X3301000101 || 100B02 || 90
3  || X3301000101 || 100B03 || 120
4  || X3302000102 || 100B03 || 130
5  || X3302000102 || 100B04 || 150
6  || X3302000102 || 100B05 || 150
7  || X3303000103 || 100B01 || 110
8  || X3303000103 || 100B03 || 115
9  || X3303000103 || 100B05 || 86
```

and i want show my output like this. 
[image]

anyone have an idea how can i show the output like that? i must using view in sql first or what i can do, because the book ID can be more

progress :
im make a query like this

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when `bookid` = ''',
      `bookid`,
      ''' then durasi end) AS ',
      `bookid`
    )  ORDER BY bookid ASC SEPARATOR ',\n'
  ) INTO @sql
from testing;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `id`, `username`, ', @sql, ' from testing GROUP BY `username`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and I managed to display it like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLaPz.png)
but i dont know how to display in table if i using 2 header like i want.

Thanks everybody for your respone. im done with this issue. i add some query and use multi query in php for display the report.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: @nXn im add my progress in question my bro.

Comment: You better do the cross tabulation in your presentation layer (PHP) code rather than in the SQL.

Comment: @slaakso I don't think I can use the crosstab method, because book data is always changing

Comment: @user2406478 The "crosstab method" is your PHP code that goes through the data and creates the headers based on that. This is job for the presentation layer, not SQL.